# How to add button to create new related resource on create / update forms in Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

In Laravel Nova I can create resources and relations between resources. However, when creating resource relations, there is no button to create a new linked resource.

It would be very useful to have this button. How can I add it there?

[image]

Comment: I found component https://novapackages.com/packages/shivanshrajpoot/nova-create-or-add. But it is crooked and abandoned.